# boost::join and boost::transformed

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use boost to join string with ",". But I have a vector of shared_ptr which I need to transform to a string.

(dumb way to do it is to use boost::transform to convert my shared pointer to a vector of strings).
But I wanted to do something like this.

NOTE: I am using VS2012 (and gcc 4.5.3 for Linux builds) and boost 1.48.0

C++ code.

```
std::string A::returnConcatString() const
{
    return boost::algorithm::join( sharedPtrList() | boost::adaptors::transformed( 
                                       [](B::ConstPtr obj )->std::string
                                       { 
                                           return ( boost::format( "%s:%s" ) % obj->string1() % obj->string2() ).str(); 
                                       } ),
                                  ",");
}
```

(BTW what happends if I use an anonymous function instead of using string2()? )

HPP Code.

```
class A
{
    public:
    /***code***/
    vector< B::ConstPtr > sharedPtrList() const;
    std::string returnConcatString() const;
}

class B
{ 
  public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<const B> ConstPtr;
  std::string string1() const;
  std::string string2() const;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can anyone please help me understand my issue?

Also, I came across this link http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3594.html (Which is exactly what I want to mimic)

When I compile this code I get an error.

```
C:\temp\tools\Windows\Boost\1.48.0\boost/utility/result_of.hpp(79): error C2903: 'result' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
C:\temp\tools\Windows\Boost\1.48.0\boost/utility/result_of.hpp(87) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::result_of_nested_result<F,FArgs>' being compiled
with
[
    F=balh::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>,
    FArgs=balh::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0> (const boost::shared_ptr<const balh::B> &)
]
C:\temp\tools\Windows\Boost\1.48.0\boost/utility/detail/result_of_iterate.hpp(33) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::tr1_result_of_impl<F,FArgs,HasResultType>' being compiled
with
[
    F=balh::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>,
    FArgs=balh::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0> (const boost::shared_ptr<const balh::B> &),
    HasResultType=false
]
C:\temp\tools\Windows\Boost\1.48.0\boost/utility/detail/result_of_iterate.hpp(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::tr1_result_of<F>' being compiled
with
[
    F=balh::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0> (const boost::shared_ptr<const balh::B> &)
]
C:\temp\tools\Windows\Boost\1.48.0\boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp(41) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::result_of<F>' being compiled
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to an [utnapistim] idea. I am using this for now. But I really wanted to write a one-liner :).

I ended up doing this.

```
std::string ret;
std::for_each ( array.begin(), array.end(), [&ret](B::ConstPtr firmware) 
                                                        { 
                                                            ret.append( ( boost::format( "[%s:%s]" ) % firmwareTypeToString( firmware->firmwareType() ) % firmware->version() ).str() );
                                                        }
                  );
```

Comment: Doing something that is readable and that actually works is not a "dumb way to do it"

Comment: I agree (I usually do that way), but I did not want to create another vector (in this case) if I could avoid it (especially since I am not going to use the new vector for anything other than boost::join).

Comment: Hrrm? Why would you need to create a vector? What happened to streaming? And loops (of `for_each`, if you insist?). You'd immediately win a lot of performance, because you're still creating lots and lots of intermediate strings, all requiring dynamic allocation.

Comment: I ended up using for_each for now. Will try to use streaming.

Comment: I've added some benchmarks for your benefit (and my curiosity) [to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23552331/85371)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just write it like this:

```
std::string returnConcatString() const {
    std::ostringstream os;
    for(auto& b : sharedPtrList)
        os << b->string1() << ':' << b->string2() << ',';

    auto s = os.str();
    if (!s.empty())
        s.resize(s.size()-1);
    return s; // moves
}
```

Amazingly, the compile times are better, and the runtime will be **a lot** better than your code would achieve.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da2e7c856d98fba4)**

And if you *really* cared about performance, I'd suggest Boost Karma:

```
std::string returnConcatString() const {
    if (sharedPtrList.empty())
        return {};

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(20 * sharedPtrList.size()); // average length preallocate?

    auto out = back_inserter(result);

    namespace k =  boost::spirit::karma;
    for(auto& b : sharedPtrList)
        k::generate(out, k::string << ':' << k::string << ',', b->string1(), b->string2());

    result.resize(result.size()-1);
    return result; // moves
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0d7df1e4c495280)** too

A performance comparison:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2MKtByb.png]

As you can see, the `stringstream` approach is only bad at small collections.

Raw data and **[benchmark code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ce130e9909d9a10)**

[image]

Comment: I've added some benchmarks for your benefit (and my curiosity)

Comment: Took the opportunity to play around with **[nonius](https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius)** too: [source code](https://gist.github.com/sehe/7efd38dbf9c143ea6626) and results [graphs](http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/nonius-q23551653.html) and stats: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7418821/

Comment: hmmm.. really interesting. Guess string stream is the "easy" way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
/* 
 * File:   ostream_join_iterator.hpp
 * Author: utnapistim :)
 *
 * Created on July 13, 2013, 1:14 AM
 */

#ifndef OSTREAM_JOIN_ITERATOR_HPP
#define OSTREAM_JOIN_ITERATOR_HPP

/**
 *  @brief  Implements join functionality directing into an ostream
 *
 *  This class provides an iterator for writing into an ostream. 
 *  The type T is the only type written by this iterator and there must 
 *  be an operator << (T) defined.
 * 
 *  @remarks This class implements functionality similar to
 *      std::ostream_iterator except it does not print a separator after the
 *      last element.
 *
 *  @param  Tp  The type to write to the ostream.
 *  @param  CharT  The ostream char_type.
 *  @param  Traits  The ostream char_traits.
 */
template<typename T, typename C=char, typename Tr=std::char_traits<C> >
class ostream_join_iterator
: public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
public:
    typedef C  char_type;
    typedef Tr traits_type;
    typedef std::basic_string<C, Tr>  splitter_type;
    typedef std::basic_ostream<C, Tr> ostream_type;

private:
    ostream_type        *out_;
    splitter_type       splitter_;
    bool                at_first_;

public:
    ostream_join_iterator(ostream_type& out)
    : out_{&out}
    , splitter_{}
    , at_first_{true}
    {
    }

    /**
     *  Construct from an ostream.
     *
     *  @remarks The delimiter is not copied, and thus must not be destroyed
     *          while this iterator is in use.
     *
     *  @param  out         Underlying ostream to write to.
     *  @param  splitter    CharT delimiter string to insert.
     */
    ostream_join_iterator(ostream_type& out, const char_type* splitter)
    : out_{&out}
    , splitter_{splitter}
    , at_first_{true}
    {
    }

    /// Copy constructor.

    ostream_join_iterator(const ostream_join_iterator& other)
    : out_{other.out_}
    , splitter_{other.splitter_}
    , at_first_{other.at_first_}
    {
    }

    ostream_join_iterator& operator=(const T& value)
    {   // add separator before the value, if not at first element
        if((not splitter_.empty()) and (not at_first_))
            *out_ << splitter_;
        *out_ << value;
        at_first_ = false;
        return *this;
    }

    ostream_join_iterator& operator=(ostream_join_iterator temp)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(out_, temp.out_);
        swap(splitter_, temp.splitter_);
        swap(at_first_, temp.at_first_);
        return *this;
    }

    ostream_join_iterator&
    operator*() {
        return *this;
    }

    ostream_join_iterator&
    operator++() {
        return *this;
    }

    ostream_join_iterator&
    operator++(int) {
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename T> using join = ostream_join_iterator<T>;
template <typename T> using wjoin = ostream_join_iterator<T, wchar_t>;

#endif  /* OSTREAM_JOIN_ITERATOR_HPP */
```

Usage:

```
using namespace std;
ostringstream   sql;
sql << "SELECT ";
transform(fields_.begin(), fields_.end(), join<string>{sql, ", "},
    [](const field& f) { return f.escaped_name(); });
sql << " FROM " << name_;
```

The transform call can easily be paced into a convenience function.